# Start or stop a linux service on remote machine by a web-site

Tags: linux, web-services

I want to develop a web application which will be able to run the linux services at remote  machine. So what technology  i must use and what are the steps i need to perform.

Answer (score 1):

don't develop one, use [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) instead